# Can you get civil war commanders to follow you?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've noticed that in each camp (Imperial and Stormcloak) there are special named NPCs, for example in the Whiterun Stormcloak Camp there is a commander named `Hjornskar Head-Smasher`.

I was wondering if at some point you can get them as followers, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without mods, you cannot.

They simply serve their purpose in the war and are used in camps to provide you with quests.

Even in the opposing side, in your case, the Imperials, have named commanders.
They serve their purpose in the war and the war only as well.

There might be a mod though, if you're using a PC, which may allow them to follow you.

Comment: Agreed. I have not successfully found a mod that would do so, afaik the named commanders remain even after the completion of the civil war arc

Comment: Yes, after finishing it both sides still have their respective commanders. May be a mod soon enough, idk.